# Python Iteration Mess

Tags: python

As you can see below I am trying to make a program that takes a file called names.txt, breaks it down into a list with .split('/n'), then adds a password for each user in the list. For some reason the for look treats the list as if it were a string, so instead of treating it like:

Bob
Charley 
Ron

It breaks it down like:

B
o
b

C
h
....
Thus giving each letter a password instead of the list itself.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a way I can test to see what the for loop is actually being given?

I have been playing with it to see if it were being given a string, but the list appears to be clealy a list when printed, so why would it be getting treated like a string in the for loop?

```
def importNames():

    try:
        file = open("names.txt", "r")
        contents = file.read()
        print(contents)
        file.close()

        return contents

    except:
        print("The file was not found.")
        print("Make sure you have a file called \"names.txt\" in the working directory (where you ran this program)")

        exit()

def createPasswordList(nameList):
    print("They are being given the standard password of \"p@ssw0rd.\"")
    #nameList = ["Pickles", "Bob's", 'wow zers john'] #This is for testing purposes. It works just fine, but the original nameList breaks down badly. 
    passList = []

    #for x, value in enumerate(nameList):
    for i in nameList:
        print(i)
        passList.append("p@ssw0rd")

    print(passList)
    return passList

def createUsers(nameList, passwordList): #takes in a list of usernames, then adds creates them. 
    for i in nameList:
        print("This will do something soon.")
        #encPass = crypt.crypt(passwordList[i],"22") #22 is a salt number, use crypt per useradd manual
        #os.system("useradd -p " + encPass + " " + nameList[i]) #useradd -p encryptedpass username

def convertNamesToList(originalList):
    print("Converting names.") #Use newline as a delimiter
    newList = originalList.split('\n')
    print(newList)
    return newList

def convertNameToUsernames(originalNames):
    print("Creating usernames")

print("This program is used to make some users.")
print("If you import a file, have it in the working directory called \"names.txt\".")

print("Would you like to import names or add them manually? (n/m)")
answer = input()

if (answer is 'm' or answer is 'M'):
    createUser()
    print("The user gets created. Good job.")

else:
    originalNames = importNames() #this will return a string of the file.
    convertNamesToList(originalNames) #convert the string to sets of names. Use newlines as delimiters. 
    #convert the names to usernames

    print("Do the users have passwords? (y/n)")
    #answer = input()
    answer = 'n' ###FORCE###
    if (answer is 'n' or answer is 'N'):
        passwordList = createPasswordList(originalNames)
```

Comment: 'convertNamesToList(originalList)' don't name it as list if it's a string. There are other typos too but this one cofused me for more than 10s. And some functions are not used/not needed for the sake of the question asked. Please edit the question so it only has the question relevant code.

Comment: Don't spam with irrelevant tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never doing anything with the return value from `convertNamesToList`. You don't store it anywhere. Then you pass `originalNames`, which is a string (you even indicate this in a comment) to `createPasswordList`.

I think you want something like:

```
originalNames = importNames() #this will return a string of the file.
listOfNames = convertNamesToList(originalNames) #convert the string to sets of names. Use newlines as delimiters. 
#convert the names to usernames

print("Do the users have passwords? (y/n)")
#answer = input()
answer = 'n' ###FORCE###
if (answer is 'n' or answer is 'N'):
    passwordList = createPasswordList(listOfNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your nameList is actually a string.  Assuming that you have one name per line of the names.txt file, Try this:

```py
def importNames():
    try:
        file = open("names.txt", "r")
        contents=[]
        for line in file.read():
            contents.append(line)
        print(contents)
        file.close()
        return contents
```

You then no not need to convert it to a list later.